# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of $x^2-4x+5=0$, find $(\alpha^3-4\alpha^2+6\alpha+2)(\beta^3-4\beta^2+6\beta+2)$

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are two roots of the equation $x^2-4x+5=0$, find $$(\alpha^3 - 4\alpha^2 + 6\alpha + 2)(\beta^3 - 4\beta^2 + 6\beta + 2)$$ using Vieta's relations.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try providing us a bit of your work. This is a typical "here's my homework, do it for me please" thread, which is usually not so well-received. Review your question by editing it and adding something to it.

Comment: noted, what other things should i add?

Answer (score 4):

$$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  + 6 x  + 2 \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  - 4 x  + 5 \right)  \cdot   \left(   x  \right)  +  \left(   x  + 2 \right)  $$

This means that your product is just
$$ (\alpha+2)(\beta+2) = (\alpha \beta) + 2(\alpha + \beta) + 4  $$

which you should now be able to evaluate